# Find html table name and scrape in R

Tags: r, xml, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table from a web page that has multiple tables. I'd like to get the "FIPS Codes for the States and the District of Columbia" table from https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html . I think the `XML::readHTMLTable()` is the right way to go, but when I try the following I get an error:

```
url = "https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html"
readHTMLTable(url, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

> named list()
>   Warning message:
>   XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html'

This is not surprising, of course, because I'm not giving the function any indication of *which* table I'd like to read. I've dug around in "Inspect" for quite a while but I'm not connecting dots on how to be more precise. There doesn't seem to be a name or class of the table that is analogous to other examples I've found in documentation or on SO. Thoughts?

Comment: I got it with `readHTMLTable(RCurl::getURL(url), ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `readLines()` to scrape the html page content and use result in  `readHTMLTable()`:

```
url = "https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html"
webpage <- readLines(url)

readHTMLTable(webpage, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)               # LIST OF 3 TABLES

# $`NULL`
#                    Name FIPS State Numeric Code Official USPS Code
# 1               Alabama                      01                 AL
# 2                Alaska                      02                 AK
# 3               Arizona                      04                 AZ
# 4              Arkansas                      05                 AR
# 5            California                      06                 CA
# 6              Colorado                      08                 CO
# 7           Connecticut                      09                 CT
# 8              Delaware                      10                 DE
# 9  District of Columbia                      11                 DC
# 10              Florida                      12                 FL
# 11              Georgia                      13                 GA
# 12               Hawaii                      15                 HI
# 13                Idaho                      16                 ID
# 14             Illinois                      17                 IL
# ...
```

For specific dataframe return:

```
fipsdf <- readHTMLTable(webpage, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)[[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `rvest` instead of `XML` is:

```
require(rvest)
read_html("https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html") %>% 
  html_table %>% .[[1]]
```